# How to monitor memory usage in Javascript / Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, monitoring

community.

In my current Javascript / Node project, I would like to ensure that some functions don't use extra memory spaces after they have been called (these functions will be called more than 100.000 times in a loop so I want to do this to avoid having no needed memory used at the end).

Do you have any tools or libraries to recommend me for what I want to do?

Comment: Node.js has a built-in profiler which uses the profiler inside V8. You can find more information in node.js docs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where is your application launched.

If it's launched on your computer, just monitor the performance of the hardware of your PC. If it's in some cloud instances like EC2 of AWS, you can use the monitoring tools of AWS. If you have your own server that doesn't have any tools of monitoring, you can try to use mp2 tool.

MP2 URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Hope this can help you.